# Flip around superview's center in iOS (RTL languages)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, right-to-left, flip

I want to flip the whole view to support right to left languages. The problem is my project doesn't use autolayout so I need to perform this flip manually.

In the same time I can't simply flip the parent view because it mirror all the labels and make them unreadable. So I need to flip parent view and some of its subviews. And in the same time I can't flip these subviews because by default they are flipped around their own centers and break the layout.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Comment: aand? flipping of images not views and flipping using autolayout. How does it answer my question?

Comment: Why not switch to auto-layout? It's probably going to be much simpler (and more robust) than whatever you could come up with to emulate this.

Comment: It is NOT simplier because the project is enough big and involves features which are enough hard to implement with autolayout